# Get Percentage of Tiered Amounts of an Integer c#

Tags: c#

Consider the following scenario on commission payouts:

- up to 100k - 1%
- 100k to 200k - 2%
- 200k+ - 3%

If a salesperson sells 400k they would receive 1% of 100k, 2% of 100k and 3% of 200k.

I know this can easily be solved with a series of if statements but I am looking for an elegant solution.

The data model is structured like so:

```
class SalesCommissionInvoiceSummaryModel
{
    public SalesCommissionInvoiceSummaryModel() { }
    
    public string SalesPerson { get; set; }
    public decimal CommissionableAmount { get; set; }
    public decimal CommissionAmount { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: The payouts don't make sense... what happens between 200k and 300k?

Comment: How about something like `commissionPct = (int)(Math.Min(CommissionableAmount, 300000) / 100000);`?

Comment: Sorry, typo.  Question has been updated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is another approach using 'Math.Min'

```
var commissionBands = new[]
        {
            new { Lower = 0m, Upper = 100000m, Rate = 1 },
            new { Lower = 100000m, Upper = 200000m, Rate = 2 },
            new { Lower = 200000m, Upper = decimal.MaxValue, Rate = 3 }
        };

var sales = 400000m; 

var commissionAmount = 0m;

foreach (var band in commissionBands)
{
    if (sales > band.Lower)
    {
        var commission = Math.Min(band.Upper - band.Lower, sales - band.Lower);
        var commissionatthisband = commission * band.Rate * 0.01m;
        commissionAmount += commissionatthisband;
    }
}

Console.WriteLine(commissionAmount);
```

Answer (score 1):

If `x` is the salary, you can compute the commission like this:

```
decimal commission = (decimal) (Math.Min(100000, x) * 0.01 + 
   Math.Min(100000, Math.Max(0, x - 100000)) * 0.02 + 
   Math.Max(0, x - 200000) * 0.03);
```

Try it out:
https://dotnetfiddle.net/leJpf2

Comment: This solution isn't very flexible or dynamic, you'd have to fiddle with the algorithm every time you'd want to make changes to the tiers. A list-based approach seems like the most elegant solution IMHO.

Comment: @silkfire I agree and that is how I would do it too in RL. It just wasn't clear what the OP meant by "elegant", especially since they don't want a "series of statements".

Comment: Can you post a list based approach?  I would like to see what you would deem the 'best' solution.

Comment: @JeremyHodge See the other answer.